# if I have an app running on android is it possible to send it commands from the computer instead of the device?

Tags: automation

Say I was running facebook for android or something, and I wanted to delete all my friends or messages. Would I have to program a macro to do this?

B. would it be possible to send the application direct commands? Delete this friend or do this? Similarly if I was going to write something for the computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in the general case, no. It's possible to send an *intent* to start an activity or service (or broadcast an intent to receivers) [using the `am` tool](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#am) from the Android shell (and therefore from a PC using `adb shell`). What you can do that way depends on what *intent filters* the app's developer has chosen to offer, and in most apps it doesn't include actions like deleting individual data items.

An alternative approach is the [`monkeyrunner` tool](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html). This is a testing tool, and it lets you write a Python script to send input events (and the like) via `adb` to an app running on your device. However, because it's designed for testing your own app, it's very limited in what it can do. To send a touch event, you have to program in the exact *x* and *y* co-ordinates that you want to touch: it can't record input and play it back later, like a general macro tool.

Comment: Thank you! This was very informative and the type of advice I was looking for!